# How do i change API end point for Knife SoftLayer Plugin?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, knife

By default, Knife SoftLayer uses API endpoint has api.softlayer.com.
:host => "api.softlayer.com"

Due to API disruption event, i need to change API endpoint to api-dev.softlayer.com.

How do i do the above change for Knife SoftLayer Plugin?

Event Description
Subject: API Disruption: On March 1st IBM Cloud will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on api.softlayer.com and api.service.softlayer.com

What Is Happening? 
On March 1, 2018 at 0900 UTC (0300 CDT) IBM Cloud Infrastructure will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and 1.1 encryption on api.softlayer.com and api.service.softlayer.com; these API endpoints will only support callers using TLS 1.2 encryption levels or higher.

When Will It Happen? 
On March 1, 2018 at 0900 UTC (0300 CDT) TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 will no longer be supported and TLS 1.2+ is required.

Who Will This Affect? 
Any users with code or services that reference the softlayer.com API endpoints for IBM Cloud Infrastructure services with encryption levels older than TLS 1.2.

Confirming and Testing Upgrades to TLS 1.2 or Higher 
The enhanced security configuration is currently enforced on alternate endpoints. You can test your services against them now to ensure there will be no disruption once the primary endpoints receive the updated configuration:

• api-dev.softlayer.com (instead of api.softlayer.com) 
• api-dev.service.softlayer.com (instead of api.service.softlayer.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only able to provide you a workaround. I recommend to wait the response from the knife-softlayer’s developers, they may provide a better solution here https://github.com/softlayer/knife-softlayer/issues/56

The knife-softlayer calls to the **fog-softlayer** gem to perform API requests, so I suggest to modify the source code of this gem since there is no way to set a different endpoint through the knife-softlayer's config file.

To know where fog-softlayer was installed you can execute following command:

```
gem list -e fog-softlayer -d
```

The answer will be something like below:

```
fog-softlayer (1.1.4)
    Author: Matt Eldridge
    Homepage: https://github.com/fog/fog-softlayer
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /var/lib/gems/2.4.0
```

Before to modify the source code, **first** go to the folder where fog-softlayer was installed, on my case was ***/var/lib/gems/2.4.0***. **Second**, make sure that you can perform API REST calls using the endpoint api-dev.softlayer.com.

`Note: I will assume that the REST endpoint is http://api-dev.softlayer.com/rest/v3`

## First Option.

Open the file ***gems/fog-softlayer-1.1.4/lib/fog/softlayer.rb*** and search the following code line:

```
SL_API_URL = ENV['SL_API_URL'] ? ENV['SL_API_URL'] : 'api.softlayer.com/rest/v3' unless defined? SL_API_URL
```

Modify it by the endpoint you want to use, for example:

```
SL_API_URL = ENV['SL_API_URL'] ? ENV['SL_API_URL'] : 'api-dev.softlayer.com/rest/v3' unless defined? SL_API_URL
```

If the endpoint points to **http instead of https**, modify the file ***gems/fog-softlayer-1.1.4/lib/fog/softlayer/slapi.rb*** as following:

Search for:

```
@request_url = "https://#{sanitize_username(username)}:#{apikey}@#{@request_url}"
```

Change it by:

```
@request_url = "http://#{sanitize_username(username)}:#{apikey}@#{@request_url}"
```

## Second Option

Open the file ***gems/fog-softlayer-1.1.4/lib/fog/softlayer/slapi.rb*** and search the following code line:

```
@request_url = "https://#{sanitize_username(username)}:#{apikey}@#{@request_url}"
```

Change it by:

```
@request_url = "http://#{sanitize_username(username)}:#{apikey}@api-dev.softlayer.com/rest/v3"
```